# PHP Random String Generator... not so random

Tags: php, random

I always thought my code generated pretty random strings but I've been pressing F5 for about 10 minutes and I display 10 strings at once and I have had THREE DUPLICATES, UNIBON, ZANOPE and ZOTAXS.

Can anyone explain why this is when I though there code be 26^6 possibilities?

```
$chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$pass = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
    $pass .= $chars[(rand() % strlen($chars))];
}
return $pass;
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

---

Using mt_rand the first duplicate takes on average between 10 and 60 seconds, that seems okay doesn't it?

```
echo 'start: '.date('H:i:s');
for ($i = 1; ; $i++) {
    $testarr[]  = passGen(6);
    $new        = passGen(6);
    if (in_array($new,$testarr)){
        echo '<br>end: '.date('H:i:s');
        echo '<br>string: '.$new;
        echo '<br>count: '.count($testarr);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You get the same three duplicates repeatedly? lol...

Comment: Maybe try `rand(0,strlen($chars))`

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){` where do you define `$len` ?

Comment: I've now added rand(0,strlen($chars)) I'm just trying to create a unique name for a company as all ideas that have been put forward to the MD have been rejected lol

Comment: If you're using PHP4 or PHP5, you should be able to use `mt_rand()` to get a better random number as `rand()` is known to have problems per the PHP manual. _see_ (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Comment: I've not used rand() with PHP, or at all really, but if its anything like java, rand() is not random. With java it uses the system time to generate a sequence of random numbers. That means that multiple calls to the same sequence will result in similar results. Hope this helps

Comment: Try mt_rand() instead of rand().

Comment: @TSUK, maybe a random generator is not best for that hahaha, but I guess that subject is beyond the scope of stackoverflow. haha. Still a great question.

Comment: Check my question on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1360/how-to-write-a-single-line-password-generator

Comment: Many thanks I've changed to mt_rand so hopefully I shouldn't see anymore duplicates

Comment: I created 1000 random strings of 6 character length, 1000 times. No duplicate were found!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you hash a random number then take a random substring from the hash?

Comment: Not a bad idea, I'm going to see how long it takes PHP to create a duplicate with mt_rand and if it's too quick then I'll try your method, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
$chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $pass = '';
        $length = strlen($chars)-1;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
            $randomNumber = rand(0,$length);
            $pass .= substr($chars,$randomNumber,1);
        }
        return $pass;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [mt_rand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php).

`mt_rand` is way better than `rand`. From the PHP manual

> Many random number generators of older libcs have dubious or unknown characteristics and are slow. By default, PHP uses the libc random number generator with the rand() function. The mt_rand() function is a drop-in replacement for this. It uses a random number generator with known characteristics using the »  Mersenne Twister, which will produce random numbers four times faster than what the average libc rand() provides.

That aside you can use this function instead to generate random strings with the length you wish ;)

```
function random($length = 10)
{      
    $chars = 'BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZAEIUO';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        $pass .= ($i%2) ? $chars[mt_rand(19, 25)] : $chars[mt_rand(0, 18)];
    }

    return $pass;
}
```

This function can be used easily to generate CAPTCHAs too ;)

Comment: What is the idea of grouping the alphabet (`$chars`), and why don't you use the whole alphabet (0-25)? It will reduce the possible combinations.

Comment: @martinstoeckli sorry my bad (^^,) I forgot to rearrange the alphabet to work for the example. I usually arrange the letters in certain order to create easily pronounceable words (i.e. constant, vowel,constant,vowel,...etc.)

Comment: @Songo if you don't mind archaic words, a sentence with 26 letters: "Cwm fjord bank glyphs vext quiz."

Answer (score 0):

I think that's just the nature of the beast.   Increase the length to 7 and add some more characters and the probability of duplicates goes down.   This is what I used to test:

```
<?php
$len = 6;
# Remove characters that can be mistaken for others, I,0,L,1 and 0
$chars = 'ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789';
for ($j=0;$j<100000;$j++) {
  $pass = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
    $pass .= $chars[(rand() % strlen($chars))];
  }
  if(isset($saved[$pass])) {
    echo "Password \"$pass\" on iteration $j has duplicate(s) from iteration(s) " . implode(',',$saved[$pass]) . "\n";
  }
  $saved[$pass][] = $j;
}
?>
```

Using mt_rand() vs rand() didn't change the output much